# Possible/Impossible Probability Question

Tags: probability

I'm not sure if there is a question like this already here, but...

I just thought of a question related to probability, and I was wondering if it was possible:

Suppose you want to ask someone to some dance. Naturally, you would need some flowers. Moreover, you want to get the best one. So, let there be $7$ roses lined up in a column, labeled $1$, $2$, $\cdots$, $7$. You can stare at one for as long as you want, but once you move forward, you cannot go back. So, a sample "pick" would be like this: Walk past flower $1$, $2$, $3$, pick up flower $4$, and be done, even though you might think $3$ was better than $4$. What would be the best strategy to pick the best flower with proof, and what would the probability be of picking the best flower?

I came up with casework(???), but it got really messy. How would one solve this, if possible?

Comment: Similar problems have been considered under various scenarios such as the [problem of choosing a secretary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secretary_problem) from a sequence of job applicants who show up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called the [Secretary Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secretary_problem), where you can also find a solution. If there are $n$ flowers, the best strategy is to note the quality of the first $n/e$ flowers, rejecting them all but noting which flower was best. After that, pick the *first* flower that's better than the first $n/e$. The probability of picking the best flower is approximately $1/e=0.36\ldots$.

Comment: Ah, I wasn't aware. Thanks!